# How to Identify currency price movement using variable "direction" to store values

Tags: r

```
library(priceR) 
a <- historical_exchange_rates("THB", to = "USD",start_date = "2010-01-01", end_date = "2021-12-31")
#Create variable direction   
a.direction <- NULL 
a.direction[a> Lag(a[,2],10)] <- 1 
a.direction[a< Lag(a[,2],10)] <- 0
```

How can I make a.direction store the values of laga[,2] instead of laga[,1]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but you can `mutate` the change in difference with the previous value using `lag` and if the value is higher you return 1 else 0:

```
library(dplyr)
library(priceR)
a <- historical_exchange_rates("THB", to = "USD",start_date = "2010-01-01", end_date = "2021-12-31")
a %>%
  mutate(direction = ifelse(one_THB_equivalent_to_x_USD - lag(one_THB_equivalent_to_x_USD, 10) <= 0, 0, 1))
```

Output:

```
          date one_THB_equivalent_to_x_USD direction
1   2010-01-01                    0.029988        NA
2   2010-01-02                    0.029988        NA
3   2010-01-03                    0.029988        NA
4   2010-01-04                    0.030692        NA
5   2010-01-05                    0.030136        NA
6   2010-01-06                    0.030338        NA
7   2010-01-07                    0.030351        NA
8   2010-01-08                    0.030339        NA
9   2010-01-09                    0.030339        NA
10  2010-01-10                    0.030339        NA
11  2010-01-11                    0.030412         1
12  2010-01-12                    0.030223         1
13  2010-01-13                    0.030391         1
14  2010-01-14                    0.030520         0
15  2010-01-15                    0.030615         1
16  2010-01-16                    0.030615         1
17  2010-01-17                    0.030615         1
18  2010-01-18                    0.030656         1
19  2010-01-19                    0.030469         1
20  2010-01-20                    0.030532         1
21  2010-01-21                    0.030375         0
22  2010-01-22                    0.030293         1
23  2010-01-23                    0.030293         0
24  2010-01-24                    0.030293         0
25  2010-01-25                    0.030813         1
26  2010-01-26                    0.030303         0
27  2010-01-27                    0.030408         0
28  2010-01-28                    0.030240         0
29  2010-01-29                    0.030301         0
30  2010-01-30                    0.030301         0
31  2010-01-31                    0.030301         0
32  2010-02-01                    0.030357         1
33  2010-02-02                    0.030418         1
34  2010-02-03                    0.030279         0
35  2010-02-04                    0.030182         0
36  2010-02-05                    0.030333         1
37  2010-02-06                    0.030333         0
38  2010-02-07                    0.030333         1
39  2010-02-08                    0.030212         0
40  2010-02-09                    0.030158         0
41  2010-02-10                    0.030266         0
42  2010-02-11                    0.030425         1
43  2010-02-12                    0.030349         0
44  2010-02-13                    0.030349         1
45  2010-02-14                    0.030349         1
46  2010-02-15                    0.030306         0
47  2010-02-16                    0.030398         1
48  2010-02-17                    0.030151         0
49  2010-02-18                    0.030091         0
50  2010-02-19                    0.030364         1
51  2010-02-20                    0.030364         1
52  2010-02-21                    0.030364         0
53  2010-02-22                    0.030276         0
54  2010-02-23                    0.030255         0
55  2010-02-24                    0.030250         0
56  2010-02-25                    0.030565         1
57  2010-02-26                    0.030405         1
58  2010-02-27                    0.030405         1
59  2010-02-28                    0.030405         1
60  2010-03-01                    0.030751         1
61  2010-03-02                    0.030879         1
62  2010-03-03                    0.030605         1
63  2010-03-04                    0.030726         1
64  2010-03-05                    0.030731         1
65  2010-03-06                    0.030731         1
66  2010-03-07                    0.030731         1
67  2010-03-08                    0.030779         1
68  2010-03-09                    0.030812         1
69  2010-03-10                    0.030645         1
70  2010-03-11                    0.030825         1
71  2010-03-12                    0.030778         0
72  2010-03-13                    0.030778         1
73  2010-03-14                    0.030778         1
74  2010-03-15                    0.030846         1
75  2010-03-16                    0.030921         1
76  2010-03-17                    0.030941         1
77  2010-03-18                    0.031040         1
78  2010-03-19                    0.031161         1
79  2010-03-20                    0.031161         1
80  2010-03-21                    0.031161         1
81  2010-03-22                    0.030989         1
82  2010-03-23                    0.030876         1
83  2010-03-24                    0.031025         1
84  2010-03-25                    0.030982         1
85  2010-03-26                    0.030956         1
86  2010-03-27                    0.030956         1
87  2010-03-28                    0.030956         0
88  2010-03-29                    0.031156         0
89  2010-03-30                    0.031144         0
90  2010-03-31                    0.031071         0
91  2010-04-01                    0.031147         1
92  2010-04-02                    0.031504         1
93  2010-04-03                    0.031504         1
94  2010-04-04                    0.031504         1
95  2010-04-05                    0.031466         1
96  2010-04-06                    0.030987         1
97  2010-04-07                    0.031064         1
98  2010-04-08                    0.031029         0
99  2010-04-09                    0.031187         1
100 2010-04-10                    0.031187         1
101 2010-04-11                    0.031187         1
102 2010-04-12                    0.031086         0
103 2010-04-13                    0.031523         1
104 2010-04-14                    0.031050         0
105 2010-04-15                    0.031162         0
106 2010-04-16                    0.031539         1
107 2010-04-17                    0.031539         1
108 2010-04-18                    0.031539         1
109 2010-04-19                    0.031279         1
110 2010-04-20                    0.031273         1
111 2010-04-21                    0.031285         1
112 2010-04-22                    0.030968         0
113 2010-04-23                    0.031298         0
114 2010-04-24                    0.031298         1
115 2010-04-25                    0.031298         1
116 2010-04-26                    0.031416         0
117 2010-04-27                    0.030918         0
118 2010-04-28                    0.031192         0
119 2010-04-29                    0.031256         0
120 2010-04-30                    0.030962         0
121 2010-05-01                    0.030962         0
122 2010-05-02                    0.030962         0
123 2010-05-03                    0.031161         0
124 2010-05-04                    0.030997         0
125 2010-05-05                    0.030790         0
126 2010-05-06                    0.030857         0
127 2010-05-07                    0.031135         1
128 2010-05-08                    0.031135         0
129 2010-05-09                    0.031135         0
130 2010-05-10                    0.030837         0
131 2010-05-11                    0.030790         0
132 2010-05-12                    0.031024         1
133 2010-05-13                    0.030897         0
134 2010-05-14                    0.030885         0
135 2010-05-15                    0.030885         1
136 2010-05-16                    0.030885         1
137 2010-05-17                    0.031337         1
138 2010-05-18                    0.030547         0
139 2010-05-19                    0.031302         1
140 2010-05-20                    0.031205         1
141 2010-05-21                    0.030938         1
142 2010-05-22                    0.030938         0
143 2010-05-23                    0.030938         1
144 2010-05-24                    0.030760         0
145 2010-05-25                    0.030950         1
146 2010-05-26                    0.030670         0
147 2010-05-27                    0.030892         0
148 2010-05-28                    0.030683         1
149 2010-05-29                    0.030683         0
150 2010-05-30                    0.030683         0
151 2010-05-31                    0.030836         0
152 2010-06-01                    0.030644         0
153 2010-06-02                    0.030805         0
154 2010-06-03                    0.030853         1
155 2010-06-04                    0.030773         0
156 2010-06-05                    0.030773         1
157 2010-06-06                    0.030773         0
158 2010-06-07                    0.030595         0
159 2010-06-08                    0.030666         0
160 2010-06-09                    0.030615         0
161 2010-06-10                    0.030827         0
162 2010-06-11                    0.031133         1
163 2010-06-12                    0.031133         1
164 2010-06-13                    0.031133         1
165 2010-06-14                    0.030768         0
166 2010-06-15                    0.031056         1
167 2010-06-16                    0.031034         1
168 2010-06-17                    0.031117         1
169 2010-06-18                    0.031006         1
170 2010-06-19                    0.031006         1
171 2010-06-20                    0.031006         1
172 2010-06-21                    0.031023         0
173 2010-06-22                    0.030927         0
174 2010-06-23                    0.031164         1
175 2010-06-24                    0.031019         1
176 2010-06-25                    0.031041         0
177 2010-06-26                    0.031041         1
178 2010-06-27                    0.031041         0
179 2010-06-28                    0.030847         0
180 2010-06-29                    0.030905         0
181 2010-06-30                    0.030752         0
182 2010-07-01                    0.031068         1
183 2010-07-02                    0.031066         1
184 2010-07-03                    0.031066         0
185 2010-07-04                    0.031066         1
186 2010-07-05                    0.031064         1
187 2010-07-06                    0.030835         0
188 2010-07-07                    0.031121         1
189 2010-07-08                    0.030969         1
190 2010-07-09                    0.031142         1
191 2010-07-10                    0.031142         1
192 2010-07-11                    0.031142         1
193 2010-07-12                    0.031002         0
194 2010-07-13                    0.030966         0
195 2010-07-14                    0.031609         1
196 2010-07-15                    0.031311         1
197 2010-07-16                    0.031094         1
198 2010-07-17                    0.031094         0
199 2010-07-18                    0.031094         1
200 2010-07-19                    0.030969         0
201 2010-07-20                    0.030985         0
202 2010-07-21                    0.030885         0
203 2010-07-22                    0.031062         1
204 2010-07-23                    0.031213         1
205 2010-07-24                    0.031213         0
206 2010-07-25                    0.031213         0
207 2010-07-26                    0.031300         1
208 2010-07-27                    0.031131         1
209 2010-07-28                    0.031052         0
210 2010-07-29                    0.031238         1
211 2010-07-30                    0.030986         1
212 2010-07-31                    0.030986         1
213 2010-08-01                    0.030986         0
214 2010-08-02                    0.031248         1
215 2010-08-03                    0.031103         0
216 2010-08-04                    0.031103         0
217 2010-08-05                    0.031312         1
218 2010-08-06                    0.031294         1
219 2010-08-07                    0.031294         1
220 2010-08-08                    0.031294         1
221 2010-08-09                    0.032080         1
222 2010-08-10                    0.031471         1
223 2010-08-11                    0.031708         1
224 2010-08-12                    0.031243         0
225 2010-08-13                    0.031436         1
226 2010-08-14                    0.031436         1
227 2010-08-15                    0.031436         1
228 2010-08-16                    0.031925         1
229 2010-08-17                    0.031425         1
230 2010-08-18                    0.031538         1
231 2010-08-19                    0.031657         0
232 2010-08-20                    0.031687         1
233 2010-08-21                    0.031687         0
234 2010-08-22                    0.031687         1
235 2010-08-23                    0.032424         1
236 2010-08-24                    0.031762         1
237 2010-08-25                    0.031678         1
238 2010-08-26                    0.031859         0
239 2010-08-27                    0.031949         1
240 2010-08-28                    0.031949         1
241 2010-08-29                    0.031949         1
242 2010-08-30                    0.032668         1
243 2010-08-31                    0.032119         1
244 2010-09-01                    0.031989         1
245 2010-09-02                    0.032283         0
246 2010-09-03                    0.032170         1
247 2010-09-04                    0.032170         1
248 2010-09-05                    0.032170         1
249 2010-09-06                    0.032858         1
250 2010-09-07                    0.032098         1
251 2010-09-08                    0.032031         1
252 2010-09-09                    0.032315         0
253 2010-09-10                    0.032488         1
254 2010-09-11                    0.032488         1
255 2010-09-12                    0.032488         1
256 2010-09-13                    0.033141         1
257 2010-09-14                    0.032554         1
258 2010-09-15                    0.032686         1
259 2010-09-16                    0.032653         0
260 2010-09-17                    0.032718         1
261 2010-09-18                    0.032718         1
262 2010-09-19                    0.032718         1
263 2010-09-20                    0.033073         1
264 2010-09-21                    0.032735         1
265 2010-09-22                    0.032814         1
266 2010-09-23                    0.033312         1
267 2010-09-24                    0.032573         1
268 2010-09-25                    0.032573         0
269 2010-09-26                    0.032573         0
270 2010-09-27                    0.033392         1
271 2010-09-28                    0.032827         1
272 2010-09-29                    0.032764         1
273 2010-09-30                    0.032878         0
274 2010-10-01                    0.033087         1
275 2010-10-02                    0.033087         1
276 2010-10-03                    0.033087         0
277 2010-10-04                    0.033895         1
278 2010-10-05                    0.033364         1
279 2010-10-06                    0.033441         1
280 2010-10-07                    0.033635         1
281 2010-10-08                    0.033629         1
282 2010-10-09                    0.033629         1
283 2010-10-10                    0.033629         1
284 2010-10-11                    0.034145         1
285 2010-10-12                    0.033801         1
286 2010-10-13                    0.033608         1
287 2010-10-14                    0.033733         0
288 2010-10-15                    0.033799         1
289 2010-10-16                    0.033799         1
290 2010-10-17                    0.033799         1
291 2010-10-18                    0.033906         1
292 2010-10-19                    0.034170         1
293 2010-10-20                    0.033375         0
294 2010-10-21                    0.033710         0
295 2010-10-22                    0.033454         0
296 2010-10-23                    0.033454         0
297 2010-10-24                    0.033454         0
298 2010-10-25                    0.034105         1
299 2010-10-26                    0.033664         0
300 2010-10-27                    0.033646         0
301 2010-10-28                    0.033553         0
302 2010-10-29                    0.033248         0
303 2010-10-30                    0.033248         0
304 2010-10-31                    0.033248         0
305 2010-11-01                    0.034320         1
306 2010-11-02                    0.033626         1
307 2010-11-03                    0.033764         1
308 2010-11-04                    0.033878         0
309 2010-11-05                    0.033958         1
310 2010-11-06                    0.033958         1
311 2010-11-07                    0.033958         1
312 2010-11-08                    0.033877         1
313 2010-11-09                    0.033665         1
314 2010-11-10                    0.033730         1
315 2010-11-11                    0.033964         0
316 2010-11-12                    0.033714         1
317 2010-11-13                    0.033714         0
318 2010-11-14                    0.033714         0
319 2010-11-15                    0.034218         1
320 2010-11-16                    0.033387         0
321 2010-11-17                    0.033418         0
322 2010-11-18                    0.033351         0
323 2010-11-19                    0.033709         1
324 2010-11-20                    0.033709         0
325 2010-11-21                    0.033709         0
326 2010-11-22                    0.034134         1
327 2010-11-23                    0.033396         0
328 2010-11-24                    0.033323         0
329 2010-11-25                    0.033387         0
330 2010-11-26                    0.033250         0
331 2010-11-27                    0.033250         0
332 2010-11-28                    0.033250         0
333 2010-11-29                    0.033078         0
 [ reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 4050 rows ]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I had tried to follow your suggestion however I had this error pop-up. Do you know how to fix it? Error in ifelse(one_THB_equivalent_to_x_USD - lag(one_THB_equivalent_to_x_USD,  : 
  object 'one_THB_equivalent_to_x_USD' not found

Comment: Hi @NapatViseshsin, It says that the column is not found. Are you sure that you exactly run my code and loaded all the packages?

Comment: I don't know somehow it is working now when I tried to rewrite your code again. Thank you for your fast response

Comment: @NapatViseshsin, Good to hear! Always good to check your code.